# Code Igniter foreach and view

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I am using a foreach loop in my controller

```
foreach ($x as $y) {
// do some stuff 
// load view
            $this->load->view('success', $data);
// $data can be multiple arrays
}
```

it does the work..but the css, js , elements in the view gets repeated ..

please guide me how to make the css ,js to load only once :)

thanks

Comment: What is in the 'success' view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely the "*do some stuff*" that needs to be put in multi-dimensional array and not directly in the `$data` array. It's better to post your "*do some stuff*" and your view, but anyway, this is how you should do it:

```
$data_holder = array();
foreach ($x as $y) {
// do some stuff 
$data_holder[] = $do_some_stuff_results;
}
$data['do_stuff_array'] = $data_holder;
$this->load->view('success', $data);
```

Now you can loop that variable in your view and not only get one result, maybe something like:

```
foreach ($do_stuff_array as $arr)
    echo "<li><img src=\"" . $arr['img_src'] . "\" alt=\"" . $arr['img_title'] . "\" /></li>";
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are loading the view in the foreach statement. Every time the loop goes around, the view gets loaded again. You need to collect your `$data` together in the loop and then call the view after the loop has finished.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($x as $y) {
// do some stuff 
// $data can be multiple arrays
}

//load the view after the foreach has finished
$this->load->view('success', $data);
```

You currently are loading the view repeatedly at each iteration of the loop.  Like this, it loads it once the loop has finished.

**Second idea**

From your code, I believe you are re-assigning your `$data` variable each iteration of the loop

```
foreach ($x as $y) {
// do some stuff 
// 
    $data['array'] = array("here","is","an","array");
}

//load the view after the foreach has finished
$this->load->view('success', $data);
```

In the above example once the view is loaded there will be one array in $data['array'] because you are overwriting it every time.  If you are wanting `$data['array']` to be a multi-deminsional array like you suggest, try this...

```
foreach ($x as $y) {
// do some stuff 
// 
    $data['array'][] = array("here","is","an","array");
}

//load the view after the foreach has finished
$this->load->view('success', $data);
```

This will append `$data['array']` instead of overwriting it, and you'll end up with an array of whatever you append to it throughout the loop.

Comment: Hi, I already tried that.. but with no success, for testing purpose ,I have added print_r to the view..but only the first array that is generated is echoed in the view..  all the function that are meant to work in the loop are working ( update DB , etc ).

Comment: ok, I'm doing a lot of assuming here because you gave us no code, but I will update my answer with another guess as to what is happening.